# how many strings you can write with the letters abcd (permutation & combination or what?)

Tags: permutations, combinations

You have 4 letters abcd.

How many 4-letter strings can you write with them?

Assumptions:
- the order is not important (aaab, abaa, baaa are same, counts 1)
- you can use same letter more than once (aaaa, aabb, etc.)

I don't want to find solution with brute force, but with some meaningful calculation.

Comment: I bet you can figure out how many 1-letter strings there are without anyone's help.

Comment: Can you see why your question is the same as asking for the number of solutions of $w+x+y+z=4$ in nonnegative integers $w,x,y,z$?

Comment: Exactly, this is what I'm wondering. Is there any formula, pattern to solve it? I already know the answer by just counting them one by one.

Comment: Try [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gerry Myerson pointed out, what you are asking is equivalent to asking how many solutions there are to the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 4$$
in the non-negative integers, where $x_1$ represents the number of $a$'s in the string, $x_2$ represents the number of $b$'s, $x_3$ represents the number of $c$'s, and $x_4$ represents the number of $d$'s.  The number of solutions of this equation is the number of ways we can insert three addition signs in a list of four ones.  For instance, 
$$1 1 + + 1 + 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 1$, and $x_4 = 1$, while $$+ 1 + 1 + 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 1$, $x_3 = 1$, and $x_4 = 2$.  The number of solutions is thus the number of ways of selecting three addition signs from $4 + 3 = 7$ symbols, which is $$\binom{4 + 3}{3} = 35$$  Using similar reasoning, you can show that the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$$
in the non-negative integers is $$\binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1}$$

Comment: Might be worth looking for duplicates --- this question has come up here many times before.